# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, oracle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES40H.png)    I am trying to insert a csv file into database by python. The database is oracle . Below is my code csv file name is PatientStatus and Table name is AIW1
import cx_Oracle as cn
import pandas as pd # pip install pandas

````
```
df = pd.read_csv('PatientStatus.csv')



columns = [ 'UNITNAME' ,
            'PATIENTSTATUS', 'PATIENTCOUNTS', 'COUNTRY','STATENAME','CITYNAME']

df_data = df[columns]
records = df_data.values.tolist()

conn = cn.connect(user="", password="",dsn="")


sql_insert = '''
    INSERT INTO AIW1
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)
'''
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.executemany(sql_insert, records)
cursor.commit();    
print('Task is complete.')
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```
I am getting the 
DatabaseError
````

Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\SOFTWA~1.SUP\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_956/3684779769.py in 
21 '''
22 cursor = conn.cursor()
---> 23 cursor.executemany(sql_insert, records)
24 cursor.commit();
25 print('Task is complete.')

```
DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you need to use a different bind placeholder syntax, not '?'.

Look at the cx_Oracle documentation for an example of efficiently loading data, see [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).  You can adjust your data to a similar format if you still want the overhead of using Pandas.

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv

# Predefine the memory areas to match the table definition.
# This can improve performance by avoiding memory reallocations.
# Here, one parameter is passed for each of the columns.
# "None" is used for the ID column, since the size of NUMBER isn't
# variable.  The "25" matches the maximum expected data size for the
# NAME column
cursor.setinputsizes(None, 25)

# Adjust the number of rows to be inserted in each iteration
# to meet your memory and performance requirements
batch_size = 10000

with open('testsp.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    sql = "insert into test (id,name) values (:1, :2)"
    data = []
    for line in csv_reader:
        data.append((line[0], line[1]))
        if len(data) % batch_size == 0:
            cursor.executemany(sql, data)
            data = []
    if data:
        cursor.executemany(sql, data)
    con.commit()
```